# Is property injection a kind of dependency injection in Spring?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, property-injection

XML

```
<bean name="helloWorld" class="com.company.HelloWorld">
    <property name="msg" value="messaging"/>
</bean>
```

JAVA

```
package com.company;

// ...

public class HelloWorld {
    private String msg;
    public void setMsg(String msg) { this.msg = msg; }
}
```

As shown above, property "msg" is injected into "this.msg" by "setMsg" method, which I understand as "Property Injection". As far as I'm concerned, Spring's DI was promoted to decouple classes, but the above codes just inject properties. And I wonder whether property injection is based on DI in Spring. Hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Injection means that the required dependencies (in your case: a simple String) are set from outside (this could be done manually or as in your case by a DI container - spring). So your class does not have to know where the value of "msg" is configured / retrieved, but it knows that (upon creation) it receives the correct value.

To answer your question: yes, property injection is a kind of dependency injection. The other possibility (that is usually preferred) is the constructor-injection, where your class has to declare all it's dependencies within the constructor. The DI framework (spring) then injects the dependencies during object construction...

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I'm concerned, Spring's DI was promoted to decouple classes,
>   but the above codes just inject properties. And I wonder whether
>   property injection is based on DI in Spring.

Assume that your `HelloWorld` class is dependent upon some other interface called `LanguageHelper`, then you can inject the implementation of `LanguageHelper` dynamically at run time (Spring container creates/manages the objects for these classes, if found on the classpath), just by specifying the implementation class name in XML as shown below (or you can use Annotations):

```
<bean id = "helloWorld" class = "com.company.HelloWorld">
      <property name = "languageHelper" ref = "languageHelper"/>
</bean>

<bean id = "languageHelper" class = "com.company.LanguageHelperImpl"></bean>
```

But, **in your case, it is a simple `String` value you want to inject to your bean dynamically** at runtime (rather than hard coding in your class directly). So, **it is an injection for which there are no additional dependencies to be evaluated**, rather just set the values using the `setter` methods provided.

So, **it is all about how we can loose couple the class (could be simple values or other class implementation) for the future changes**, rather than directly hard coding inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Flowers ["Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern"](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) should be a great read about Inversion of Control design pattern.

As per Martin Flower's post, injection can happen using constructor, setter injection and interface. Spring do support all 3 injection pattern.